# Hash script data

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, transaction, script, hash

I want to understand a bit better the hash-script-data functionality from cardano-cli. I checked the source code but had no luck in understanding how this hash is made.

From the examples, if we run:

```
cardano-cli transaction hash-script-data --script-data-value 42
```

We get the following hash:

```
9e1199a988ba72ffd6e9c269cadb3b53b5f360ff99f112d9b2ee30c4d74ad88b
```

However if we try to do a simple SHA256 hash of a 42 value we get:

```
73475cb40a568e8da8a045ced110137e159f890ac4da883b6b17dc651b3a8049
```

Also tried in the Plutus object format:

```
{
  "constructor": 0,
  "fields": [{
    "int": 42
  }]
}
```

but none of those match the hash generated by cardano-cli.

Also tried innumerous other alternatives but obviously I'm missing something, anyone knows what's the process for generating this hash?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing step would be converting the `ScriptData` into
CBOR prior to hashing.

In the case of `ScriptDataNumber` `42` the CBOR Hex is `"182a"` which is a bit simplified for Numbers vs more complex `ScriptData`. The CBOR [Jump Table](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8949#appendix-B) shows that `0x18` indicates `unsigned integer (one-byte uint8_t follows)` followed by `2a` which is `42` in hex.

Or using Haskell:

```
let plutusData = PlutusCore.Data.I 42
print $ Base16.encode $ BSL.toStrict $ Codec.Serialise.serialise plutusData
-- "182a"
print $ Cardano.Api.hashScriptData $ Cardano.Api.Shelley.fromPlutusData plutusData
-- "9e1199a988ba72ffd6e9c269cadb3b53b5f360ff99f112d9b2ee30c4d74ad88b"
```

and using libsodiumjs as example to hash:

```
var libsodiumWrappers = require("libsodium-wrappers");
var _sodium = libsodiumWrappers;

(async () => {
  await _sodium.ready;
  const sodium = _sodium;
  var h = sodium.crypto_generichash(32, sodium.from_hex('182a'));
  console.log(sodium.to_hex(h));
})();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Regarding objects/json files, are we supposed to also convert to CBOR? For example a datum object like `{"constructor": 0,"fields": [{"int": 4}]}`, I transform into CBOR: `a24b636f6e7374727563746f7200466669656c647381a143696e7404` and when I hash it I get `5677bf1048dad6dce36483d2bec0fafc71f5dc9b01a2b1326c6443c2cd264b50`, but if I do the same with cardano-cli I get `8bb54ceaee2f57731094a2e96b8ad87bcc8988b1fa838e8c833eb3b72eae29a1`. Is there any additional step in this case?